# Windows command 'start /max' - what is the equivalent for 'call'?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

Inside a batch file, I need to run an executable in a maximized terminal.

I've found saveral answers, all suggesting the use of `start /max`.

However, when using `start`, the terminal automatically shuts down upon completion.

So I want to use `call` instead, but I cannot find the equivalent syntax.

I've also tried executing `mode cols=200 lines=300` before executing `call`, but it just opened a large terminal, not setup in full-screen, which made it even less convenient than a small terminal.

Comment: have you tried `start /max /wait`?  (may or may not work with your EXE)

Comment: `start` has another undesired feature - it opens the executable in a new terminal and closes the current one. I want a message `choice /m "Process complete; press X or simply close the window" /n /c X` displayed at the end of the executable, which I can't quite achieve with `start`.

Comment: if `/wait` doesn't work, use `tasklist` in a loop.

Comment: mode.com cannot switch the console to full-screen mode or even maximize the window. It simply modifies the screen buffer size and resizes the viewable window as big as the monitor allows. Also, in NT 6 (i.e. Vista up to Windows 8.1) the console's full-screen mode was removed. It was restored in NT 10 but without restoring the console API's function to enable full-screen mode. so it only supports toggling full screen via Alt+Enter or F11.

Comment: By default `start` calls `CreateProcess` with the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag, unless the `/b` option is used that forces reusing the current console. If and only if a new console is allocated will its `/max` option have any effect on a console app. This option gets passed as `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` in the `wShowWindow` field of the process `STARTUPINFO`. Then, when the child process is starting up, if it allocates a new console, it passes this startup information to its instance of the console host process (conhost.exe).

Comment: I have no idea where you would get the idea that `start` terminates either the current shell or its console. If you don't `/wait`, your script is probably just exiting normally. And if the cmd.exe instance that's executing your script is the only process attached to the console, then both will of course exit. But this has nothing to do with `start`.